# Flutter setState rebuilding all children

Tags: flutter

I've got a parent widget that has a Stack with two children.
When using setState in the parent, without actually changing something (setState with empty body) why are the build methods of the children being called?

Is it not the case that flutter rebuilds only the widgets with dirty params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flutter will run the build function for all children (exception being const Widgets). It will not rerender them though. If Flutter finds that nothing changed in the widget, it will just reuse the previous render.

The program has no way of knowing if state has changed, unless it checks by running build.

Comment: I see. so running the child's build method doesn't actually rebuild it (for an unchanged child)?

Comment: @Fridge It does "rebuild" it. But it will only render the widget again, if something changed. There is definitely still a performance impact rerunning build on a bunch of widgets constantly. If that becomes an issue, you can always split your widget tree up more. But usually it should be completely fine.

Comment: @Fridge No problem at all :) If you want a visual representation of what gets rebuilt and when, have a look at the Flutter DevTools "Repaint Rainbow" feature.

Comment: @Fridge Also feel free to accept the answer if you feel like it helped.